# CakePHP pagination issues

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having trouble getting pagination to work when conditions are involved in the query. In my OrdersController I have the following pagination to display all of the entires and it works perfectly

```
$order_list = $this->Paginate('Order'); 
$this->Set('orders', $order_list);
```

When I try to find the orders for a given user it immediately throws an error and I can't even figure out what it's related to.

```
$order_list = $this->Paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Order.userid' => $id)
);
$data = $this->Paginate('orders', $order_list);
$this->set(compact('data'));
```

In my OrdersController I also have listed:

```
public $paginate = array(
    // other keys here.
    'maxLimit' => 20
);
```

When I try to run this I get an error that says "An Internal Error Ocurred" which isn't helpful at all.

When I print the search results for $order_list it just spits out the parameters I'm searching for, so I don't even think it's searching.

```
Array ( [conditions] => Array ( [Order.userid] => 4 ) )
```

It basically just tells me what I'm searching for and doesn't actually search the orders table for the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = $this->paginate('Order', array('Order.userid' => $id));
$this->set(compact('data'));
```

You seem to mix two approaches of defining extra parameters to paginate by. See [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) for more info.

Comment: Awesome, you're the man! I would upvote and accept but I don't have enough reputation. If you upovte my question maybe that'll bump me over.

Comment: Glad to help! Shouldn't you be able to accept answer already? I mean is that even restricted by rep?